# what's the default value if no @table annotation?

Tags: jpa, annotations

[What's the default value if no @table annotation ?](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Table.html)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the link you have added, after looking at the default values for each of the optional attributes (**catalog**, **name**, **schema**) the JPA implementation will default to a table:

- with the **name** equal to the entity class,
- belonging to the default **catalog** (specified in persistence.xml, if any)
- and belonging to the default **schema** for the user (the db user specified in persistence.xml)